# Getting the date as per the format in which month name is coming as first

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am getting the string in this formatas shown below

```
03-12-2018
```

I want to convert this into as below format as per Java 8 standards please advise

```
December 03 , 2018
```

what I have tried is shown below but i was not succeessful , please advise how to acheieve the same

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    String actualDate = "03-12-2018";

    Date date = sdf.parse(actualDate);

    String month_name = month_date.format(date);
    System.out.println("Month :" + month_name);
```

Comment: Please explain "not successful".

Comment: I was not successful in the result of output of my program

Comment: @user1493927 I think he meant you should copy paste the output you got so we can see it too., note that your format of `yyyy-MM-dd` does not seem to match the format you have in `"03-12-2018"`

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What @ScottHunter meant (I think), was that you should tell us *precisely* how your observed outcome differed from the expected `December 03 , 2018`. Please paste your output, including any error messages or stacktrace you might see. We can help you a lot better from there, so it’s for your own sake (and because trying to answer questions where we have to guess is frankly no fun).

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter originalFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
    DateTimeFormatter monthFirst = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG)
            .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String actualDate = "03-12-2018";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(actualDate, originalFormatter);
    String monthName = date.format(monthFirst);
    System.out.println("Month :" + monthName);
```

Output:

> Month :December 3, 2018

Since you are using Java 8 (and even if you didn’t), avoid the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. Use the built in formats where you can rather than rolling your own.

### What went wrong in your code?

You parsed a string of `03-12-2018` with a format of `yyyy-MM-dd`. So this parses into the 2018th day of the 12th month of year 3 CE (2015 years ago). There obviously weren’t 2018 days in December. So it would have been fair to expect an exception. This is just one of the points where `SimpleDateFormat` is troublesome: with standard settings it just keeps counting days into the following months and years and ends up at June 9 year 9, that is, 5 and a half years later. Next you formatted this date with a formatter including month name and year, it seems you had forgot the day of month. Anyway it printed as `Jun 0009` (which you should have told us in your question so that we could see what was wrong; this information can be very helpful in trying to solve your problem).

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of choosing the correct format (and applying a correct `Locale`):

```
 DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("LLLL dd, yyyy");
 System.out.println(f.format(yourDate));
```

Btw it's in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> ...
>   Number/Text: If the count of pattern letters is 3 or greater, use the Text rules above. Otherwise use the Number rules above.
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

String actualDate = "03-12-2018";

Date date = sdf.parse(actualDate);

String month_name = month_date.format(date);
System.out.println("Month :" + month_name);
```

Comment: You are using terrible classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: I just modified the code provided by the person who asked the question to solve his issue.

Comment: And those classes used in your Answer and in the Question are themselves part of the problem. (A) The Question is trying to represent a date-only value, but is using a date-with-time-of-day class: `java.util.Date`. So that is a misfit of data type. (B) Add on the complicating issue of time zone, because the `java.util.Date` class is in UTC but that fact is masked by your code and the code of the Question. The correct best solution is shown in [the Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52293487/642706) showing the proper fit for purpose: `java.time.LocalDate` (without zone & time).